# How do I fix this flutter iOS build error related to Ruby?

Tags: ios, flutter, build

When i try to build in Flutter for iOS.. I am getting the error as follows:

````
```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require':
    dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): no suitable image
    found.  Did find: (LoadError)´´´
````

Could you suggest me how can I overcome this error?

Comment: Check if ruby framework is installed in your machine if not you need to install that.